# Напишите программу, которая будет проверять значение в переменной login и выводить соответствующее сообщение

Tags: javascript, for, login

//Не могу понять, почему код сразу выводит console.log("Нет логина"):

```
let form = prompt('Введите свой статус', 'Сотрудник или Директор');
let login = "";
if (login == 'Сотрудник') {
  console.log('Привет');
} else if (login == 'Директор') {
  console.log ('Здравствуйте')
} else if (login == '') {
  console.log('Нет логина')
} else {
  console.log('');
}
```

//В тренажере Эльбрус, проверку проходит, а в консоли браузера нет.

Comment: заносятся данные в form, а проверяется login.....И действительно....почему работает так?...)))

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало.